# Limitations w.r.t. scale of decimal numbers in HTML5 automatic validation?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a web app using HTML/JS/CSS. I have a field as follows
`<input type="number" min="0" max="100" step="0.001">`

I am using the `:invalid` pseudo class to style the field with a pink background for values outside the limits. This seems to work fine to an extent.

For example, 45.1, 45.01, 45.001 show up as valid values. As soon as I start increasing the number of 0s, it flags the field as invalid because the `:invalid` pseudo class gets set. So far, so good.

Here's the problem: this only works till 45.0000000001 (10 decimal places). When I increase the decimal places beyond 10, e.g. 45.00000000001, the :invalid pseudo class disappears. It has something to do with the number of decimal places, not the number itself. 45.9999999999 (10 9s) is invalid but 45.99999999999 (11 9s) isn't.

What am I missing?

The documentation is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) doesn't mention any such constraint. I can use regex but that would be a workaround.